# mysql update a column based on nearest value of other column

Tags: mysql

i have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exam_results` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_rank` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_level_2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_rank_2` int(11) NOT NULL,
);
```

**total_level** and **total_rank** and **total_level_2** have values but **total_rank_2** is empty

i want to select value of **total_level_2** and find closest one inside **total_level**,
then update **total_rank_2** with **total_rank** of found row

how can i do it in an a query?

---

**update:**

```
total_level    |    total_rank    |    total_level_2    |    total_rank_2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1500           |    100           |    2000             |    ?
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1700           |    90            |    3500             |    ?
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2000           |    70            |    1500             |    ?
```

for example the last row after update should be 100.
beacuse the closest value of **total_level_2** in last row is inside first row , so **total_rank_2** of last row will be **total_rank** of first row

the table after update:

```
total_level    |    total_rank    |    total_level_2    |    total_rank_2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1500           |    100           |    2000             |    70
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1700           |    90            |    3500             |    70
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2000           |    70            |    1500             |    100
```

Comment: Could there be a level 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempresults_cal AS (select cni.*,
                       (select   total_rank
                        from     exam_results ci
                        where ci.analyze_id="'.$Params->get('analyze_id').'"
                        order by abs(total_level - cni.total_level_2)
                        limit 1
                       ) as new_rank
                from exam_results cni;

                UPDATE exam_results
                INNER
                  JOIN tempresults_cal
                    ON tempresults_cal.id = exam_results.id 
                   SET exam_results.total_rank_2 = tempresults_cal.new_rank
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Update table set total_rank_2 =(Select total_rank
  from table
 where total_leve<=total_level_2
 order by total_level Desc
 limit 1)
```